# Characteristic polynomial of $A^{-1}$ as function of characteristic polynomial of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an invertible $n\times n$ matrix over a field $\mathbb{F}$. Let $c_A(x)$ denote the characteristic polynomial of $A$, and $m_A(x)$ the minimal polynomial of $A$.

Show that $c_{A^{-1}}(x)=x^n[c_A(0)]^{-1}c_A(\frac{1}{x})$, and also that $m_{A^{-1}}(x)=x^k[m_A(0)]^{-1}m_A(\frac{1}{x})$, where $k=\deg(m_A(x))$

Could anyone hint me how to start?

Comment: OK here's a hint: $(xI-A)=x(A^{-1}-x^{-1}I)A$.

Answer (score 0):

Show that if $\lambda$ is a root of multiplicity $m$ of $c_A$ (in an algebraic closure of $\Bbb F$), then $\frac1\lambda$ is a root of multiplicity $m$ of $c_{A^{-1}}$ and vice versa.

For minimal polynomial, multiply the formal expression $m_A(A)$ by a suitable power of $A^{-1}$ and vice versa.